# PHP OAuth with twitter behind a proxy

Tags: php, twitter, oauth, proxy

I am currently using [php oauth](http://php.net/manual/en/book.oauth.php) to connect my site with twitter, but the problem is that my machine is behind a proxy and I got the error

`OAuth::getRequestToken(https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token): failed to open stream: Network is unreachable`

How can I do configuration in such case? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying to do much the same.

There appears to be no way to expose the curl object used by the oauth library in order to set the options put forward by Avanche.

It's possible to change the oauth lib from using curl to use streams instead. This opens the possibility of setting the default stream context options to use your proxy, then letting oauth use that.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/oauth.setrequestengine.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-set-default.php

This sounds like it should work, but our configuration consistently gave "400 - Bad request" errors. This is probably a problem at our end, so you should have a better time with it.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do in this case, is find in the OAuth object where curl is configured and add the following options:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $yourproxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
```

Answered for historical purposes